# Sharing Set Not Working

Tags: sharing-sets

I have a custom object called Requisition. The idea is that a community user will create a requisition. The requisition will be re-assigned to a queue for processing.

This is all working fine. I have defined a sharing set for the community so that the community users will still be able to view requisitions while they are being worked.

[image: Sharing Set]

After a user creates a requisition it is re-assigned and the user immediately loses visibility. Am I Missing something with my sharing set?

### Note

I am good enough with apex that I could write a trigger to automatically share the record whenever the owner changes. I just don't think that is/should be necessary.

### Update

I noticed my list views were all set to "my requisitions" I changed them to show "all requisitions" instead and still no luck.

### Update 2

When I copy/paste the Id of the requisition into the URL I get a page not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screen shot, it looks like you need to [apply the Sharing Set to a Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm) to get it to grant access:

> 5. Select the profiles of the users to whom you want to provide access.

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I missed that....